# Pyramid not rendered correctly when not sorting data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have searched for a pyramid chart using d3js and have not found any example that renders a pyramid chart without sorting the data. I am trying adapt [this pyramid](http://bl.ocks.org/ronakrrb/73e9204a66e2a9c1fee8) chart example by dropping the sorting portions of the code.

Here's what I have ([fiddle form](http://jsfiddle.net/dhrubs/tbsrqga7/)):   .

```js
d3.pyramid = function() {
  var size = [1,1],
      value = function(d) { return d.value},
      coordinates;
  
  var percentageValues = function (data) {
    var values = data.map(value);
    var sum = d3.sum(values, function (d){
      return +d;
    });
    var percentValues = data.map(function (d,i){
      d.value = +values[i];
      return values[i]/sum*100;
    });
    
    //I don't want sorting, i want to display in the same order data is passwed, i pass high-medium-low
    //like in high chart https://jsfiddle.net/nc7bzdx3/7/
   /*  percentValues.sort(function(a,b){
      return b-a;
    }); */
    
    
    return percentValues;
  }
  var coordinatesCalculation = function(data){
    var w = size[0],
        h = size[1],
        ratio = (w/2)/h,
        percentValues = percentageValues(data),
        coordinates = [],
        area_of_triangle = (w * h) / 2;
    function d3Sum (i) {
      return d3.sum(percentValues,function (d, j){
        if (j>=i) {
          return d;
        }
      });
    }
    for (var i=0,len=data.length;i<len; i++){
      var selectedPercentValues = d3Sum(i),
          area_of_element = selectedPercentValues/100 * area_of_triangle,
          height1 = Math.sqrt(area_of_element/ratio),
          base = 2 * ratio * height1,
          xwidth = (w-base)/2;
      if (i===0){
        coordinates[i] = {"values":[{"x":w/2,"y":0},{"x":xwidth,"y":height1},{"x":base+xwidth,"y":height1}]};
      }else{
        coordinates[i] = {"values":[coordinates[i-1].values[1],{"x":xwidth,"y":height1},{"x":base+xwidth,"y":height1},coordinates[i-1].values[2]]};
      }

    }
    coordinates[0].values[1] = coordinates[coordinates.length-1].values[1];
    coordinates[0].values[2] = coordinates[coordinates.length-1].values[2];
    var first_data = coordinates.splice(0,1);
    coordinates = coordinates.reverse();
    coordinates.splice(0,0,first_data[0]);
    return coordinates;
  } 
  function pyramid(data) {
    var i = 0,
        coordinates = coordinatesCalculation(data);
    
  /*   data.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.value - b.value;
    }) */
    
    data.forEach(function(){
      data[i].coordinates = coordinates[i].values;
      i++;
    })
    return data;
  }
  pyramid.size = function(s){
    if(s.length === 2) {
      size = s;                    
    }
    return pyramid;
  }
  pyramid.value = function(v) {
    if (!arguments.length) return value;
    value = v;
    return pyramid;
  };
  return pyramid;
}



var data = [
        {priority: 'High', count: 1000, key: 1},
        {priority: 'Medium', count: 120, key: 2},
        {priority: 'Low', count: 60, key: 3}
    ];
    
    var svg;
    var CANVAS_CLASS = "canvas";
    var MARGIN = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 40};

    var width = 400, height = 300;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#F24936", "#F6BF18", "#FFFFFF", "#0000FF"]);


    var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + 300)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr('class', CANVAS_CLASS)
                .append("g");


    var pyramid = d3.pyramid()
            .size([width, height])
            .value(function (d) {
                return d.count;
            });

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('linear-closed')
            .x(function (d, i) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .y(function (d, i) {
                return d.y;
            });
            
    var pyramidData = pyramid(data);

    var g = svg.selectAll(".pyramid-group")
            .data(pyramidData)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "pyramid-group");

    g.append("path")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return line(d.coordinates);
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.priority);
            });

    g.append("text")
            .attr({
                "y": function (d, i) {
                    if (d.coordinates.length === 4) {
                        return (((d.coordinates[0].y - d.coordinates[1].y) / 2) + d.coordinates[1].y) + 5;
                    } else {
                        return (d.coordinates[0].y + d.coordinates[1].y) / 2 + 10;
                    }
                },
                "x": function (d, i) {
                    return width / 2;
                }
            })
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.priority+ '_'+d.count;
            });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}

 .arc path {
                stroke: #fff;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I have commented out sorting, but the output is not correct: the areas do not correspond to the unsorted values. How do I make the pyramid chart show the areas of input data in the order they are provided?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you seeking to do by modifying how the coordinates get calculated? What sort of modification are you looking at? Also, what does a correct output look like?

Comment: i want to render the pyramid in the same order e.g High on top then Medium in middle and Low at the bottom like in jsfiddle. but pyramid does not reflect correct percentage size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the correct area's aren't being rendered for each segment. If we look at the original code, there are two inverted sorts, `b-a` and `a-b`, both based on the value property. It appears as though that when sorting by percentages the sorting is opposite as when sorting the data by value. By dropping all sorting we don't have datum and percentage ordered oppositely.

So if we reverse the order of the percentages we should get the proper alignment of datum with area:

```js
d3.pyramid = function() {
  var size = [1,1],
      value = function(d) { return d.value},
      coordinates;
  
  var percentageValues = function (data) {
    var values = data.map(value);
    var sum = d3.sum(values, function (d){
      return +d;
    });
    var percentValues = data.map(function (d,i){
      d.value = +values[i];
      return values[i]/sum*100;
    });

    percentValues.reverse();
    
    
    return percentValues;
  }
  var coordinatesCalculation = function(data){
    var w = size[0],
        h = size[1],
        ratio = (w/2)/h,
        percentValues = percentageValues(data),
        coordinates = [],
        area_of_triangle = (w * h) / 2;
    function d3Sum (i) {
      return d3.sum(percentValues,function (d, j){
        if (j>=i) {
          return d;
        }
      });
    }
    for (var i=0,len=data.length;i<len; i++){
      var selectedPercentValues = d3Sum(i),
          area_of_element = selectedPercentValues/100 * area_of_triangle,
          height1 = Math.sqrt(area_of_element/ratio),
          base = 2 * ratio * height1,
          xwidth = (w-base)/2;
      if (i===0){
        coordinates[i] = {"values":[{"x":w/2,"y":0},{"x":xwidth,"y":height1},{"x":base+xwidth,"y":height1}]};
      }else{
        coordinates[i] = {"values":[coordinates[i-1].values[1],{"x":xwidth,"y":height1},{"x":base+xwidth,"y":height1},coordinates[i-1].values[2]]};
      }

    }
    coordinates[0].values[1] = coordinates[coordinates.length-1].values[1];
    coordinates[0].values[2] = coordinates[coordinates.length-1].values[2];
    var first_data = coordinates.splice(0,1);
    coordinates = coordinates.reverse();
    coordinates.splice(0,0,first_data[0]);
    return coordinates;
  } 
  function pyramid(data) {
    var i = 0,
        coordinates = coordinatesCalculation(data);
    
  /*   data.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.value - b.value;
    }) */
    
    data.forEach(function(){
      data[i].coordinates = coordinates[i].values;
      i++;
    })
    return data;
  }
  pyramid.size = function(s){
    if(s.length === 2) {
      size = s;                    
    }
    return pyramid;
  }
  pyramid.value = function(v) {
    if (!arguments.length) return value;
    value = v;
    return pyramid;
  };
  return pyramid;
}



var data = [
        {priority: 'High', count: 1000, key: 1},
        {priority: 'Medium', count: 500, key: 2},
        {priority: 'Low', count: 160, key: 3}
    ];
    
    var svg;
    var CANVAS_CLASS = "canvas";
    var MARGIN = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    var width = 400, height = 150;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#F24936", "#F6BF18", "#FFFFFF", "#0000FF"]);


    var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + 300)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr('class', CANVAS_CLASS)
                .append("g");


    var pyramid = d3.pyramid()
            .size([width, height])
            .value(function (d) {
                return d.count;
            });

    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate('linear-closed')
            .x(function (d, i) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .y(function (d, i) {
                return d.y;
            });
            
    var pyramidData = pyramid(data);

    var g = svg.selectAll(".pyramid-group")
            .data(pyramidData)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "pyramid-group");

    g.append("path")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return line(d.coordinates);
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.priority);
            });

    g.append("text")
            .attr({
                "y": function (d, i) {
                    if (d.coordinates.length === 4) {
                        return (((d.coordinates[0].y - d.coordinates[1].y) / 2) + d.coordinates[1].y) + 5;
                    } else {
                        return (d.coordinates[0].y + d.coordinates[1].y) / 2 + 10;
                    }
                },
                "x": function (d, i) {
                    return width / 2;
                }
            })
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.priority+ '_'+d.count;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew,  by reversing the percentage values fixes the issue.

Comment: @reactdev, no problem, sorry if I was a bit confused on the issue at first.

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing the question and answering. I accepted the answer.

Comment: @reactdev, I'm always a bit cautious in editing questions - glad you were ok with it (there's always the option to roll back an edit if you weren't happy), thanks for the accept.

Comment: Wondering how to add padding between the pyramid triangles. like in d3.v3.5, there is d3.layout.pie().padAngle(.02) which sparates the slices.